# Как открыть файл и записать в него , начиная с конца. Python

Tags: python, файлы

Есть текстовый файл , который открывается с запуском скрипта и туда записываются данные. Каждый раз записывается с начала файла, а мне надо , чтобы данные записывались начиная с конца, то есть предыдущие данные должны сохраниться. Можно использовать

```css
_file = open('file.txt','r+')
_file.read()
_file.write('a')
```

Но не затратно ли это ? Есть другие способы ?

Comment: `open('file.txt','a')` ;)

Comment: ...............a)

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен мод `a` (append), а не `r+`.

Содержание файла `text.txt` перед стартом скрипта:

```
text that beings here from start
```

Код скрипта:

```
with open("text.txt", "a") as f:
    for i in range(100):
        f.write("\n"+str(i))
print("done")
```

Содержание файла `text.txt` после работы скрипта:

```
text that beings here from start
0
1
2
3
4
5
...
99
```